How to correctly use Hoodie's INSERT_OVERWRITE_TABLE operation?
I have a spark job that pulls in data via an API. The API does not have any sort of timestamp that lets me know when a record was recently modified so i have no choice but to constantly refresh all the data periodically since i cannot use upsert mode.
My pipeline is written in pyspark 3.4.1 and i am using hoodie to write the extracted data as parquet file to AWS S3. The hoodie writer is configured with INSERT_OVERWRITE_TABLE (i also tested with ``INSERT_OVERWRITE`) mode but all subsequent runs after the initial execution, i get the following error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o540.save.
: org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieException: hoodie table at
s3://my_bucket/my_folder/dataset/ already exists.
I was under the impression that this directory/directory contents will be overwritten and recreated everytime the spark application runs. My pipeline works only if i delete all the contents in s3://my_bucket/my_folder/dataset/. Am i understanding this hoodie mode incorrectly or are there other configs i need to set as well?
